# How to create the rotating bottle effect?

Tags: javascript, animation

I just wanted to ask for advice on how the effect with the rotating bottle on scrolling is done so smoothly on this website: https://takeboost.com/
Is this an SVG file or is it frames that are loaded upon scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `F12 > Network` and refreshing the page, we can see 299 `.jpg` are loaded by JavaScript, these images are then drawn to a `canvas` when scrolling.

You can also use `F12 > Network` to find related JavaScript code:

1. Hover on the `Initiator` column of these image requests in `F12 > Network`
2. Click first clickable js link
3. Click "Pretty-print", the code to load these images will be highlighted.